# Convert number to money in european format with amperstamp

Tags: sql-server

ValueHi i am trying to convert some number to money format 
I use this code

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), cast([Opportunity].SalesValue as money), 1) as 'Value'
```

and i have this result 2,500,000.00
is it possible to have ' instand of , ?
I tried

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), cast([Opportunity].SalesValue as money), 1),',',''') as 'TCV (TEUR)'
```

but ''' is not allowed, how can I tell to sql that this is special character?

Comment: Replace ''' to '''' it will work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should type ' twice, this will tells to SQL that ' mark should be interpreted as a symbol.

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), cast([Opportunity].SalesValue as money), 1),',','''') as 'TCV (TEUR)'
```

Also you can use CHAR(39) to achieve the same result as this:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), cast([Opportunity].SalesValue as money), 1),',',CHAR(39)) as 'TCV (TEUR)'
```